# javascript serilizer & deserilizer datetime issue

Tags: javascript, .net, json, serialization, json-deserialization

Actually my database resides at CST time zone and all the datatime value are stored in CST only.
In one of my application screen, we are showing the datetime value among with other columns.
while loading the data into grid it is showing properly but whenever i try to sort the grid with any of the column, The datetime column in showing in UTC rather than CST.

```
EntityMapper.MapList<TestsModelMapper>(response.TestEntity, TestModel);
JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

SearchedTestHiddenField.Value = jsSerializer.Serialize(TestModel);
string jsonString = SearchedTestHiddenField.Value;

JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
IList<TestsModel> TestModel = (IList<TestsModel>)jsSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString,typeof(IList<TestsModel>));
```

Comment: Which issue and what's your question (read more here: [ask] and [mcve])